# [Flutter]How to download video to app, and make it accessible only through the app (Similarly to Youtube/Netflix)

Tags: flutter

i'm fairly new to Flutter and is currently working on a course app that requires downloading the videos to the app.
The downloaded video will only be accessible through the app just like Youtube and Netflix, and will be hidden/encrypted from gallery. Would greatly appreciate if someone if someone could point me in the right direction in building this feature.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

On iOS and Android your app has it's own isolated folder for storing documents. Items stored there are not intended to be accessible to the user outside of your app. This folder isn't scanned by the Gallery or accessible to other apps on the device. (However, with a little effort a user can access the files so this is not a complete solution where security is an concern. You would need to add encryption if you didn't, say, want a motivated user to copy the video file to a PC and be able to play it.)

the [path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider) plugin gives your Flutter app common file locations on a device. The private app folder location is retrieved with `getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()`

---

"Download video" is a vague requirement. Most video on the internet (Netflix, Youtube) is provided via HLS or DASH for streaming, which you do download but the video is split up into many files- sometimes thousands of files for a single video. The [dart:http](https://pub.dev/packages/http) package is likely what you're going to want to use to get/download the files (unless the video files aren't available via HTTP/HTTPS, then you'll need a different transport-specific library, like FTP, RTSP, etc.)